# How to run an external PHP script silently within a PHP script?

Tags: php

For example:

Content of **server-a.com/test.php**:

```
echo 'hello world one';

// now I need to call server-b.com/test.php here silently
// without interfering with user experience

echo 'hello world two';
```

---

Content of **server-b.com/test.php**:

`mail($foo, $bar, $qux); header('location: http://google.com');`

---

Now running `server-a.com/test.php` should output `hello world one hello world two`. And it should not redirect to google.com even though `server-b.com/test.php` was called successfully.

Comment: Your question does not relation show a between the two scripts. which one is calling what?

Comment: if you don't want  header() to run make it conditional on some parameter you can decide when to pass.

Comment: @LordLoh. If you run `server-a.com/test.php`, you also silently run `server-b.com/test.php`

Comment: Who down voted? Explain what's wrong with this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [file_get_contents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)

```
file_get_contents("server-b.com/test.php");
```

or [Curl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)

```
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "server-b.com/test.php"); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, TRUE); // remove body 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE); 
curl_exec($ch);
```

Answer (score 0):

use this function file_get_contents():

```
file_get_contents("server-b.com/test.php");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Symfony2's Process component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html) for that.
Example:

```
use Symfony\Component\Process\PhpProcess;

$process = new PhpProcess(<<<EOF
    <?php echo 'Hello World'; ?>
EOF
);
$process->run();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the location header with [`header_remove`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header-remove.php). After you include server-b.com/test.php just call

```
header_remove('Location');
```

Comment: How can you include a php file which is on another server?